# Matplotlib won't let me savefig() and show() the same figure

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

After upgrading to Yosemite from Mountain Lion I've spent quite a bit of time getting all my packages working again, but I'm left with one weird issue. When I try to both save and show a matplotlib plot I get the following error:

```
Assertion failed: (s->stack->next != NULL), function CGGStackRestore, file Context/CGGStack.c, line 77.
```

The following short script produces this error, but works as expected if I comment out either the savefig or the show command.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
def main():
    pl.plot(range(10),range(10))
    pl.savefig('bugplot.jpg')
    pl.show()
    return
```

I'm using python 2.7, installed through homebrew, with my scipy, numpy and matplotlib packages all updated to the latest versions through pip. Saving a figure as well as showing it was working fine before I upgraded to Yosemite (and performed all the associated updates to xcode,homebrew,python,etc.), but I couldn't say exactly which versions I was using before. I can work around this problem of course, but it is bugging me, and I like getting a quick look at my figures while saving them, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Installing and maintaining scientific packages on Windows/OSX can be a pain. You may want to have a look at Continuum Analytics `anaconda`, which in my opinion can safe you a lot of frustration. That said, this error is weird. It seems that this error is not raised somewhere from python code. What happens if you change backends? Do you see this issue for all backends?

Comment: Possible related: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4194

Comment: That github topic looks to be exactly the same problem. I'm surprised (and disappointed) that I didn't manage to find that myself. And it also shows me a simple solution, in that the problem only exists when trying to output to jpg. 

I've tried changing backends, but couldn't find any that work on my system from the list of accepted inputs to matplotlib.use(). Agg doesn't support jpg, and gtk complains about missing _backend_gdk, even though I literally just installed it, and reinstalled matplotlib for good measure. Any others I should try?

Comment: Anaconda is a good tip as well. I did use that at some point, but I can't quite remember why I've gone back to using a package manager. I'm guessing I needed something that wasn't included in it at some point, found instructions on how to install that through homebrew, and ended up getting all of python through homebrew as well.